# !important css tag throwing Webpack config error during testing

Tags: javascript, npm, cypress

having some trouble troubleshooting this error and can't seem to find anyone else having the problem. I'm getting it while running a basic Cypress test with this code.

```
describe('Donate Box Loads', function () {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/title/when-they-see-us")
})
```

The page loads fine, but clearly Cypress is having an issue with the !important css tags in my css files.Does anyone know how to fix?[image]

Comment: It has nothing to do with `!important` token. It probably because you forgot to include a sass loader in webpack.

Comment: Ah you are correct. Thank you

Comment: if it is the issue, may be you can delete this question?